# How to find last updated column with data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have columns as

```
FIRST_NAME 
LAST_NAME 
MONDAY 
TUESDAY 
WEDNESDAY 
THURSDAY 
FRIDAY 
ADDRESS 
AGE
```

I want to scan from `MONDAY` column to `Friday` column, and find out from them only that which is last data loaded column, like:

- If I have data in `MONDAY` , `TUESDAY` , `WEDNESDAY`, so my result from the query should be `'WEDNESDAY'`.
- If I have data in `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday` then result from the query should be `Thursday`.
- If I have data only in `Monday` then result from the query should be `Monday`

Comment: You could use coalesce(Friday, Thursday.....) but really the problem is the design here is not well normalized. Entries like this require more than 1 table. A table for the personal data and another for transactions. Also, you should not store age. You should store age and calculate age. When you store age the data is stale as soon as you save it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your requirements you need the following query:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN NOT Friday IS NULL THEN 'FRIDAY'
         WHEN NOT Thursday IS NULL THEN 'THURSDAY'
         WHEN NOT Wednesday IS NULL THEN 'WEDNESDAY'
         WHEN NOT Tuesday IS NULL THEN 'TUESDAY'
         WHEN NOT Monday IS NULL THEN 'MONDAY'
         ELSE 'ALL NULLS' END AS Result          
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Some might find that `when Friday is not NULL` reads a little more naturally than `when not Friday is NULL`. Yoda likely would disagree.

Answer (score 1):

COALESCE is best suited for your use case.

```
SELECT COALESCE(FRIDAY, THURSDAY, WEDNESDAY, TUESDAY, MONDAY) AS SELECTEDDAY
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

For reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @vani-malge : Please accept this as your answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: You'd want to reverse the order of the days, but even then this will return the value in the column rather than the column name.

Comment: If you are getting null values, that means all the column values are null. Can you check if atleast one of the column has value.